# ScrollView: How to handle large amount of content?

Tags: swiftui

This piece of code is kind of stress test for a `ScrollView`. While a `ForEach` loop with 3000 items is rendering acceptably fast, 30000 takes long, and 300000 forever (I stopped after 3 minutes).

However, there are situations where you have a lot of content to scroll, imagine a timeline with zoomable scales (decade / year / month / day). In this case, there may be days across 50 years to display, and the user must have the chance to zoom in and out in order to change the scale.

The question for me is therefore: what strategies are possible with SwiftUI in order to optimize caching, prefetching etc., or to find out which part is to be displayed next after the user scrolled, and to prevent the model from calculating widths?

To be more precise: The model knows all data to display. The `ScrollView` must be provided with a content view that has the width of all items to display. This width is my problem: how can it be determined in a way that makes sense, and without having all items to be available?

```
struct TestScrollView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true, content: {

            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 1) {

// 3000 is working, 30000 not well, 300000 takes forever:
                ForEach(1 ..< 30000) { index in

                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.yellow)
                        .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 300, minHeight: 500, idealHeight: 500, maxHeight: 500, alignment: .bottom)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
``
```

Comment: BTW, in my project, a List showing about 2000 items is OK. However, when I apply a filter to items, for example, remain 1000 items, it takes so much time to re-render the list, seems that calculating each cell should remain or not is time-consuming. So I think it's not suitable to use even List to show such amount of items for now because of its poor performance.

Comment: in TVOS when i try your code i cannot swipe since it is not a `Button` or a `.focusable()`, when i add a `.focusable()` i can't get 20 - 30 items to scroll with a reasonable performance, is there any solution for scroll on apple tv with SwiftUI ?

Answer (score 3):

There was a trick old times for having horizontal `UITableView` that is using now for reversal filling (bottom to top) that you can use it here:

- Use a vertical list
- Rotate it 90˚
- Rotate all items of it -90˚

now you have horizontal `List`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
                ForEach(1 ..< 30000) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                }
        }
        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
        .position(x: 10, y: 200) // Set to correct offset
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a `Scrollview` instead of a `List`? A `List` would reuse the cells which is much better for performance and memory management. With the list when a cell scrolls out of sight, it gets removed from the view which helps greatly with performance.

For more information about the difference in performance please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942163/ios-choice-a-uiscrollview-or-a-uitableview)

```
    var body: some View
    {
        List
        {
            ForEach(1..< 30000) {
                index in

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 300, minHeight: 500, idealHeight: 500, maxHeight: 500, alignment: .bottom)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** Since I miss-read the original question because the scrollview is horizontal.

An option would be to wrap an UICollectionView into UIViewRepresentable see [here for the dev talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/) and [here for an example implementation](https://www.averyvine.com/blog/programming/2019/06/07/uicollectionview-and-uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource-in-swiftui) this would let you display it as a horizontal view while getting the performance benefits of a list

Comment: well, I need a horizontal scroll with lots of custom stuff. I don‘t think a list is adequate for my use case.

Comment: Horizontally scrolling through 30,000 items is a really bad idea. You should consider changing your UI interaction model to fit the system conventions better.

Comment: added details for horizontal scroll

Comment: I‘m trying to optimize the model in a way that it provides only the items required for the screen. How can I retrieve the scroll position in order to feed it back to the model and to update the data accordingly?

Comment: My situation was a bit different, but I had been getting poor performance with an outer `ScrollView`. I've now switched to using a `List` and the performance problem went away.